# Unix programming if statement

Tags: ksh

What's wrong I get an error : `./greater[4]: [: argument expected`

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "please enter a nuber " 
read $num
if [$num -ls 20 ]; then
 echo "your nuber is greater than 20 "
else
echo "your number is less then 20 "

 fi
```

Comment: Also, your logic is backwards: if `[ $num -lt 20 ]` (`-ls` is incorrect) then "your number is less than 20" not greater than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read $num
```

That above will read input into a variable which name is stored in `$num`, which "obviously" isn't correct. Change it to `read num` and it will work as expected.

---

With the above change you'll also need to add a space after `[` on the line quoted below:

```
if [$num -ls 20 ]; then
```

Otherwise the command will look like the below code-snippet if the user enters *123*, and your shell will complain about the command `[123` isn't found, or similar.

```
if [123 -ls 20 ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after `[`:

```
if [ $num -lt 20 ]; then
```

The `[` command is actually the same thing as the `test` command, and as a command it needs a space between the command name and its first argument.